# Set Variable Based on Formula Error/Value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate a sheet (set on manual calcs) continuously until there are no more errors. I have the following code below, but it appears that it does not recognize the variables I set, as the values for those variables are the result of a formula and not actually what is in the cell as a value. I saw another question on a somewhat related topic that used a worksheet function, but have been unable to see how I can fit it into my code. Usually if I run this process without VBA code, I do the manual calcs 5-6 times, but for the code I would like to be more accomodating. The rest of my code works, it is just this part that is messing up the process. I suppose I could just calc the sheet like I normally would on a loop for some arbitrary number of calcs, but if possible I would like it to calc only if the two errors below are present. See below for piece of code.

```
  Dim n As Variant
  Dim na As Variant
  n = "#N/A Requesting Data..."
  na = "#N/A Invalid Override"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  For Each Cell In Range("AZ13:BQ82")
      If Cell.Value = n Then
          Sheet1.Calculate
      End If
  Next

  For Each Cell In Range("AZ13:BQ82")
      If Cell.Value = na Then
          Sheet1.Calculate
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: and ? Is there something wrong to your code ? An error ?

Comment: After I run the code, there are still errors remaining in the cells I am calcing, which would have dissapeared if the code above worked.

Answer (score 1):

[`IsError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177273.aspx) is your friend

```
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  For Each Cell In Range("AZ13:BQ82")
      If IsError(Cell.Value) Then
          Sheet1.Calculate
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: +1. But I would add a `DoEvents` after the `Calculate`.